# NotesJsonNavigator and international characters

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have json data that I want to use in a lotusscript library.
I use NotesJsonNavigator to navigate through the data.
If I set preferUTF8 to false, the values in NotesJSONElements are strings, however it drops international characters like ö, å, ...

If I set the parameter preferUTF8 to true, the values in my NotesJSONElements are byte arrays.
How can I convert these byte arrays into Strings, taking international characters into account?

Example:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
'URL Parameters have to be UTF-8 encoded.
Dim url As string
URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Malm%C3%B6%2C%20Sweden&key=<My Google API Key>"

'Creating the request
Dim webRequest As NotesHTTPRequest
Dim response As Variant
Set webRequest = session.createhttprequest()

'Get response as byte array
webrequest.preferstrings = False
response  = webrequest.Get(URL)

'Throw error if response status is not OK
If InStr(webRequest.Responsecode, "200 OK") = 0 Then
    'Return Status is not OK
    Error 1000, "Request returned response code " + webRequest.responseCode
End If

'Create the JSON NAVIGATOR
Dim jsnav As NotesJSONNavigator
If Not IsArray(response) Then Error 1000, "JSON is nothing"
Set jsnav = session.CreateJSONNavigator(response)
'Get data as Strings
jsnav.Preferutf8 = False


'Declaring json specific elements
Dim el_address As NotesJSONElement
Dim el_state As NotesJSONElement

'Retrieving the address...
Set el_address = jsnav.getelementbypointer("/results/0/formatted_address")
Print el_address.value

'Retrieving state
Set el_state = jsnav.getelementbypointer("/results/0/address_components/1/long_name")
Print el_state.value
```

This prints

Malm, Sweden

Skne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be fixed in the next 10.0.1 FP. Keep an eye out for DCONB8F6JV in the fix list.